# TCP/UDP port vs Port Forwarding

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, tcp, udp

One of the things that I feel I lack a good enough understanding in is networking/internet protocols. So maybe my question is dumb.

If I understand it correctly, TCP/UDP ports are "local" to the server and client software and are only relevant on the devices maintaining the connection; and the ports tacked on to external IP addresses with a colon are "local" to the router in that they are only relevant to the router and in the interest of finding a device without a unique external address.

---

So, if I am correct, I just want to make sure, if you have a function defined:

```
TCPserver.listen(string ip, int port)
```

Then I could do (depending on implementation of course):

```
TCPserver.listen("123.456.789:18735", 1337)
```

And the two ports would have nothing to do with each other and could never interfere with each other?

---

If I am not correct, what am I getting wrong?

Comment: -1 You write `"If I understand it correctly, TCP/UDP ports are "local" to the server and client software"` WHAT?  `"and are only relevant on the devices maintaining the connection"` WHAT?   `"and the ports tacked on"` WHAT? `"and the ports tacked on to external IP addresses with a colon are 'local' to the router in that they are only relevant to the router "` NO, and WHAT? `"and in the interest of finding a device without a unique external address"`  WHAT? Who is trying to find devices with duplicate IP addresses. Why would u have devices w/duplicate IP addresses? Wat on earth ave u bin readin

Comment: What would you mean if you were to say that TCP/UDP ports were not local to the server?    What would you mean if they were relevant to devices "maintaining" the connection. What on earth does "maintaining the connection" mean.   You have written an unbelievable amount of gibberish, it is so far from reality. It's like you're just using your imagination.

Comment: And this line `TCPserver.listen("123.456.789:18735", 1337)` may well be wrong.. quite possibly it should be 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0  and  not have a port number within what perhaps should only be the IP. What language is it?  And `1337` is kiddie hacker speak, which normally isn't based on a proper understanding.

Comment: as in, most likely the first parameter to that function should only be an IP

Answer (score 0):

The listener is on the local machine.  The IP specified for the listener tells it what hardware (network) interface to watch, obviously on the specified port.

If the listener is configured on an external address (external to the machine, as in not `localhost`), then incoming request may be received from other machines on the network.

In most cases, as seems to be your case, there would be a router installed between the Internet connection and the computer.

The router's job is to direct traffic to the proper machine.  In order to make your service available from the Internet, you would therefore need to tell your router that a request on the public IP (WAN/Internet) has to be forwarded to the correct server.

This is done by enabling port forwarding in the router's configuration, choosing the public port and the destination private IP and port.

Here is a simple example of a web server setup that would bypass an ISP block of incoming port 80 requests:

```
WAN/public IP: 1.2.3.4
LAN: 192.168.0.0/24 (router's IP would typically be 192.168.0.1)
web server: 192.168.0.10:80
```

Since port 80 is blocked by the ISP, we'll use port 8080 instead, so our link would be `http://1.2.3.4:8080`.  In the router we would forward port 8080 to `192.168.0.10:80`.

Comment: So if I'm hosting a server on a device connected to a router that has port forwarding set up, then what does a client need to know to send a message. Could `socket.send("public.ip:port", "message")` be sufficient, or would they need to specify a TCP port as well?

Comment: Your command already includes a port.  The client operating system's connection handler will assign a local port to manage the outgoing connection but your application doesn't need to know that.  Note that sending data on a socket is a much lower level operation than sending a chat message for example.  To be useful, it needs to operate at a the application layer, therefore following a certain protocol such as FTP, HTTP, SSH, etc.

Comment: If the client can not target a TCP port, and the port tacked onto the public ip is just for a potential router, which then forwards the message, then what does "listening to a port" achieve?

Comment: I explained that in my answer.  The server behind the router listens to specific ports for that service.  Different ports will typically be used for the machine to provide different services.

Comment: Nobody "listens to a port"  A computer might listen ON a port. The official, standard terminology is bad enough as it is, there's no reason to deviate from it and make it even worse